# Overleaf BioMed template, question marks printed instead of affiliation numbers

Tags: overleaf, affiliation

I am working on a LaTeX file on Overleaf by using the [BioMed article template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/biomed-central-article-template/gcgcxphtpccx).
I am listing the names and the affiliations of mine and another coauthor (2 in total), but for some weird reason the LaTeX PDF file shows two question marks (??) rather than the subscript numbers 1 and 2, for for our names and for our affiliations.

Overleaf processes the file without finding errors, and raises the warnings:

```
Reference `aff1thanks' on page 1 undefined on input line 164.
Reference `aff2thanks' on page 1 undefined on input line 168.
```

The weird thing is that I do not use the `aff1thanks` and the `aff2thanks` in my LaTeX code...
I using standard commands that are included in the BioMed template:

> \author[addressref={aff1},
> email={davidechicco@davidechicco.it}
> ]{\inits{DC}\fnm{Davide} \snm{Chicco}}
> \author[addressref={aff2},
> email={jurman@fbk.eu} ]{\inits{GJ}\fnm{Giuseppe} \snm{Jurman}}

Please also see the screenshot below of what I see in the PDF file:
[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: my main file was using the `\bibliographystyle{bmc-mathphys}` command but the `bmc-mathphys.bst` file was missing.
I don't know why it impacted the affiliation numbers but that's okay.

Comment: This is only partly correct. I found out that the **bibliography style file** (`bmc-matphys.bst`) and the **bibliography file** itself (`bmc_article.bib`) must both be present for the numbering to work.